# Independence on a collection of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence

I have a question about Independence on a collection of events from the statement in Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis' "Introduction to Probability" (page 40):

> Independence means that the occurrence or non-occurrence of **any number** of the events from that collection carries no information on the remaining events or their complements. For example, if the events $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$ are independent, one obtains relations such as
> $$P(A_1 \cup A_2 | A_3 \cap A_4) = P(A_1 \cup A_2)$$
> or
> $$P(A_1 \cup A_2^c | A_3^c \cap A_4) = P(A_1 \cup A_2^c)$$

I don't really understand this statement and can't generalize the statement from the examples given. Can someone please elaborate on what they mean? Does "**any number**" mean either a union or an intersection of events? I would really appreciate it if you can give more examples as well. Thank you!

Comment: For mutually independent events $A_1, ..., A_k, A_{k+1}, ..., A_{k+m}$, any intersection or union of events or complements of events in the collection $\{A_1, ..., A_k\}$ is independent of any intersection or union of events or complements of events in the collection $\{A_{k+1}, .., A_{k+m}\}$. Knowing anything about the first collection of events tells you nothing about the other collection.

Answer (score 1):

Pairwise independence differs from mutual independence - later needs additionally to former independence for any chosen event from intersection from all others. In your example, if we say, that $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are mutual independent, then this means, that independent are events: $A_1$ and $A_2$, $A_1$ and $A_3$, $A_3$ and $A_2$, $A_1$ and $A_2 \cap A_3$, $A_2$ and $A_1 \cap A_3$, $A_3$ and $A_2 \cap A_1$.

There is nice counterexample, that from only pairwise you cannot get mutual. One of the most beautiful moment in probability theory.

**Note:** it can be shown, that in case of mutual independent, for example, $A_1$ is independent also from $A_3 \cup A_2$:
$$P\left( A_1 \cap (A_3 \cup A_2) \right)=P\left( (A_1 \cap A_3)  \cup (A_1 \cap A_2) \right) =  \\ = P\left( A_1 \cap A_3 \right)+P\left( A_1 \cap A_3 \right) - P\left( A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \right)= \\ =P\left( A_1  \right)P\left( A_3  \right)+P\left( A_1  \right)P\left( A_2  \right)-P\left( A_1  \right)P\left( A_2  \right)P\left( A_3  \right)= \\=P\left( A_1  \right) P\left( A_3 \cup A_2 \right)$$

Comment: Is $A_1 \cup A_2$ and $A_3$ independent? Also, how about the complements of the events that you listed?

Comment: Answer on first question added. For second: if one from the pairs $A$ and $B$, $A^c$ and $B$, $A$ and $B^c$, $A^c$ and $B^c$ is independent, then three others automatically become also independent.

Comment: If, for example, you have 4 events that are mutually independent, are $A_1 \cup A_2$ and $A_3 \cup A_4$ independent? How about $A_1 \cup A_2$ and $A_3 \cap A_4$? How about $A_1 \cap A_2$ and $A_3 \cap A_4$?

Comment: All comes  using same technique as I show in answer.

Comment: They're independent as well, right?

Comment: Right - it's very easy to obtain: denote, for example one from unions, or one from intersections, by variable and you'll find same expressions as I wrote above.  Is your question answered now?